# jQuery .change function onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that is triggered onchange like:

```
$(".option-image select").change(function()
```

The function changes an image based on a select drop down.

Now I'd like to manipulate the select on load and call the function so the image will change.
I've tried with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#option-236").children("option[value='57']").prop('selected',true).change()
});
```

While that does change the select to the correct one, the image is not changed, making me believe that `$(".option-image select").change(function())` is not triggered.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `change` event only happens when the user selects an option, not when you do it with code.

You can trigger the event using the `change` method, it doubles as both setting the event and triggering the event. You trigger the event on the select element, not on the option element:

```
$("#option-236").change();
```

---

Side note: You only need to set an option as selected if you have a multi-select, otherwise you can just use the `val` method:

```
$("#option-236").val('57');
```

Then you can chain the methods:

```
$("#option-236").val('57').change();
```